# How do I reset iCloud podcasts syncing?

Tags: itunes, icloud, data-synchronization, podcasts

So, since I updated iTunes to version 11.1, my podcasts library went a little crazy. Some episodes were deleted from my Mac and all episodes are now marked with the little blue pin  (saying they're unwatched/unplayed). I'm not sure this is the default behaviour now in this iTunes version, I hope it's just a bug.

So I decided I want to get rid of everything and just start over. I unsubscribe from all podcasts and delete all the episodes from my MacBook and iPad. The problem is that it seems iCloud is still holding info about my podcasts and brings back the weird situation mentioned above. How do I wipe out everything iCloud knows about my podcasts and start again freshly?

Answer (score 1):

Unsubscribe from your podcasts and resubscribe.  It really sucks but it is the only option.